# Scripting with bcdedit

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, command-prompt, bcdedit

After rebuilding a HDD using ImageX and a WIM, the BCD sometimes gets corrupted. I therefor need to rebuid the BCD from a script running unattended in a command prompt.

The below code does the job, when entered manually. I need help to automate it (see further below code example):

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force
attrib -h -s C:\boot\BCD
del C:\boot\BCD
bcdedit.exe /createstore c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /store c:\boot\bcd.temp /create {bootmgr} /d "Windows Boot Manager"
bcdedit.exe /import c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /timeout 10
attrib -h -s C:\boot\bcd.temp
del c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /create /d "Microsoft Windows" /application osloader
bcdedit.exe /set {GUID} device partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /set {GUID} osdevice partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /set {GUID} path \Windows\system32\winload.exe
bcdedit.exe /set {GUID} systemroot \Windows
bcdedit.exe /displayorder {GUID}
```

As started above, I need to run this in a unattended command prompt. The output from the 6th last statement "bcdedit.exe /create /d "Microsoft Windows" /application osloader" is a newly creates GUID. This ID is needed in the following commands.

How do I load this new GUID from bcdedit to a variable I can call in the following code?

Best Regards
Henrik V. Nielsen

Comment: Hello. I forgot to mentions that the OS is Win7 Embedded 32bit. I am running the script from a WinPE USB disk.

Answer (score 5):

If other should face the same problem, I solved it by adding the following line.

```
For /F "tokens=2 delims={}" %%i in ('bcdedit.exe') do (set _NEWGUID=%%i)
```

This works because there is only one GUID in the file.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easier way.

When creating a new entry BCD accepts all GUIDs in the Form **aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee** (number of digits **8-4-4-4-12**)

This means you can define an GUID an don´t have to search the GUID with the For-Loop.

It´s working for me.

Comment: Hello mr netlord,

Sounds interesting. I will try to implement next time I need to update the script.

Comment: How do you specify your own GUID? That's what I came here looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on Henrik's code

This takes the GUID created from BCD into a text file and the for loop gets the GUID from the file

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force
attrib -h -s C:\boot\BCD
del C:\boot\BCD
bcdedit.exe /createstore c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /store c:\boot\bcd.temp /create {bootmgr} /d "Windows Boot Manager"
bcdedit.exe /import c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /timeout 10
attrib -h -s C:\boot\bcd.temp
del c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /create /d "Microsoft Windows" /application osloader>GUID.txt
For /F "tokens=2 delims={}" %%i in (GUID.txt) do (set _NEWGUID=%%i)
bcdedit.exe /set %_NEWGUID% device partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /set %_NEWGUID% osdevice partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /set %_NEWGUID% path \Windows\system32\winload.exe
bcdedit.exe /set %_NEWGUID% systemroot \Windows
bcdedit.exe /displayorder %_NEWGUID%
```

Answer (score 0):

Dylan Grasha
Your answer has some errors and I have added some enhancements to make it more complete.

```
@Echo Off
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootsect.exe /nt60 C: /force
attrib -h -s C:\boot\BCD
del C:\boot\BCD
attrib -h -s C:\boot\bcd.temp >nul
del C:\boot\bcd.temp >nul
bcdedit /createstore c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /store c:\boot\bcd.temp /create {bootmgr} /d "Windows Boot Manager"
bcdedit.exe /import c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /timeout 10
attrib -h -s C:\boot\bcd.temp
del c:\boot\bcd.temp
bcdedit.exe /create /d "Microsoft Windows" /application osloader>GUID.txt
For /F "tokens=2 delims={}" %%i in (GUID.txt) do (set _NEWGUID=%%i)
bcdedit.exe /set {%_NEWGUID%} device partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /set {%_NEWGUID%} osdevice partition=C:
bcdedit.exe /set {%_NEWGUID%} path \Windows\system32\winload.exe
bcdedit.exe /set {%_NEWGUID%} systemroot \Windows
bcdedit.exe /displayorder {%_NEWGUID%}
del guid.txt
cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way for fixing BCD.

```
bcdboot c:\windows
```

for example replaces all bcdedit commands from question.

See explanations for [using bcdboot to fix BCD](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html).

The utilities bcdboot and bootsect can fix all boot problems (regarding initial boot sequence).

sfc.exe can fix corrupted system files.